# How to Make Browsers Show Changes to a Static Site

Tags: html, caching, browser

So I've got a simple static site that I update on a pretty regular basis. (It's a blog, built with Jekyll.) The problem is that browsers* seem to be caching the pages and hiding updates from returning viewers.

One obvious option is to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) for the landing page where the updates mostly occur. Except I'm not necessarily against caching; I just want to make sure that a newer version on the server supersedes the cached version. Thoughts on how to accomplish this?

*I've only observed this directly on Chrome, but I imagine the same problem exists with other browsers.

Comment: nice one.. I like it. And also want to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching control can be set to have time limits as specified in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html).

This is done by setting HTTP headers similar to:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 1998 14:19:41 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Jun 1998 02:28:12 GMT
```

The automatic creation of these headers varies with webserver, but for Apache, it can be done using [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html).